# How would i get the average of the three rows. (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, average

I was able to get the result of the three hospitals i needed. Know I'm trying to figure out how to average the three results together to get a overall group results.

```
   SELECT H.[Hospital Name],
    Format(1.0* Avg (Case When s.[PhysicianQuestion]>3 Then 1.0 Else 0 End),'P2') As    [Physician 
   Top Box],
   Format(1.0*Avg (Case When s.[NurseQuestion]=4 Then 1.0 Else 0 End),'P2') As [Nurse Top Box],
  Format( 1.0*Avg ( Case When s.[FacilityQuestion]=4 Then 1.0 Else 0 end),'P2') As [Facility Top Box]
  From surveyresponses as S
  Join Visits as V  on v.AccountNumber=S.AccountNumber
   join Hospitals as H on  H.HospitalID=V.HospitalID
   Group By [Hospital Name] 
   Order By [Hospital Name]


     Results 
     Central Hospital       74.04%  76.15%  71.26%
      Desert Flats Hospital 67.79%  68.99%  73.96%
     Mercy Valley Hospital  74.93%  76.45%  73.88%
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is needed to get the overall performance of the hospital staff

```
select [Hospital Name],
    format( (([Physician Top Box] + [Nurse Top Box] + [Facility Top Box] )/3), 'P2') AS
    [Overall Hospital Performance]
from (
    select 
        h.[Hospital Name],
        avg(case when s.PhysicianQuestion > 3 then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Physician Top Box],
        avg(case when s.NurseQuestion = 4     then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Nurse Top Box],
        avg(case when s.FacilityQuestion = 4  then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Facility Top Box]
    from surveyresponses as s
    inner join Visits as v    on v.AccountNumber = s.AccountNumber
    inner join Hospitals as h on h.HospitalID    = v.HospitalID
    group by h.[Hospital Name]
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you could add another level of aggregation:

```
select
    format(avg([Physician Top Box]), 'P2') [Avg Physician Top Box],
    format(avg([Nurse Top Box]),     'P2') [Avg Nurse Top Box],
    format(avg([Facility Top Box]),  'P2') [Avg Facility Top Box]
from (
    select 
        h.[Hospital Name],
        avg(case when s.PhysicianQuestion > 3 then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Physician Top Box],
        avg(case when s.NurseQuestion = 4     then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Nurse Top Box],
        avg(case when s.FacilityQuestion = 4  then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Facility Top Box]
    from surveyresponses as s
    inner join Visits as v    on v.AccountNumber = s.AccountNumber
    inner join Hospitals as h on h.HospitalID    = v.HospitalID
    group by h.[Hospital Name]
) t
```

Note that I moved the formating to the the outer query, after all artihmetic computations.

---

On the other hand, if you want the average of the three column values for each row returned by the query, you can do:

```
select
    [Hospital Name],
    format([Physician Top Box], 'P2') [Physician Top Box],
    format([Nurse Top Box],     'P2') [Nurse Top Box],
    format([Facility Top Box],  'P2') [Facility Top Box],
    ([Physician Top Box] + [Nurse Top Box] + [Facility Top Box]) / 3 [Avg Top Box]
from (
    select 
        h.[Hospital Name],
        avg(case when s.PhysicianQuestion > 3 then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Physician Top Box],
        avg(case when s.NurseQuestion = 4     then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Nurse Top Box],
        avg(case when s.FacilityQuestion = 4  then 1.0 else 0 end) As [Facility Top Box]
    from surveyresponses as s
    inner join Visits as v    on v.AccountNumber = s.AccountNumber
    inner join Hospitals as h on h.HospitalID    = v.HospitalID
    group by h.[Hospital Name]
) t
```

Note that the subquery is not strictly necessary here; it just avoids repeting the conditional expressions multiple times.

Comment: Hello,  thank you for the help, I am trying to get a output of avg result from the hospital for example,   Central Hospital     results are    74.04%  76.15%  71.26% i want to avg those results together to get a composite score

Comment: @LamarReynolds: ok, I understand. See the second query in my answer.